# I get the following error on SQLAlchemy, Python: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 5 elements

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, one with around **9971581** rows, the other being only **6628** rows representing only a date column. I want to get rows from the first table that have a date time matching with the dates in the second table.

PS: If there is any other alternatives with Pandas or anything else, then I'm okay with it as long as it would be fast.

```
query = engine.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'DateTime' IN (SELECT '0' FROM truedate) ORDER BY 5")
raw = pd.DataFrame(query.fetchall())
raw.columns = query.keys()
raw

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 5 elements
```

Comment: Your query is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your query currently isn't returning anything.
You're also trying to match on two strings:

- the *string* 'DateTime', and
- the *string* '0'.

Change your query to use an inner join:

```
query = engine.execute("""SELECT my_table.* 
                          FROM my_table 
                              JOIN truedate 
                              ON my_table.DateTime = truedate.your_date_column
                          ORDER BY 5;"""
```